# How to reduce the storage of a GCP cloud SQL instance that is connected with Upstream and Downstream streaming dataflow jobs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-sql

We are using a Cloud SQL instance in GCP with 15(SSD) of data(Postgress). There are some streaming dataflow jobs that are writing data to the source schema of the Cloud SQL and there are some other streaming dataflow jobs that reads data from the target schema of the Cloud SQL. there are some ETL running from Source to target schema. We need to reduce the SSD storage by half as it is overprovisioned. From the google cloud documentation I found that we can not reduce the storage capacity of an existing instance. What is the best approach here? Should I create a parallel Cloud SQL instance? In this case how do I manage the upstream and downstream dataflow jobs as both are streaming in nature? Can I achieve it without having no down time or with minimal downtime?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we don't have the option to manually minimize or reduce storage size on a Cloud SQL instance. Documentation on [monitoring disk availability](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/using-ood-recommender) only provides recommendations to **increase** storage when disk space is low.

Here are some of the suggestions that I've personally performed on my end to reduce disk size:

- [Create a migration job](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/postgres/create-migration-job)

  - This provides you the option to specify the storage type and capacity of your Cloud SQL instance.
- [Reach out to Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)

  - Google Cloud support team will provide you **self-service** option to adjust the storage size based on your preference.
- File this one as a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

  - In this way, the option will be available on your Cloud SQL instance without having to migrate it or reach out to Google Cloud support. However, feature requests will undergo a review from their engineering team first and it doesn't have a specific ETA. You can still keep track of its progress once the ticket has been created.

For streaming dataflow jobs, you may check out this documentations below:

- [Dataflow SQL](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/sql/dataflow-sql-intro)
- [Streaming Engine for Streaming jobs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/streaming-engine)

You can check out the [Dataflow overview](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/overview) for your reference.